# How to set a universal colorscale for plotly offline?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, plotly, data-science

I would like to set a colorscale universally for `plotly` in offline mode, specifically `jupyter notebook`. This is so that, I don't need to input the parameter for every plot.

I wasn't able to find anything in their documentation on colorscales, over [here](https://plot.ly/python/colorscales/).

EDIT: So, I found this function in `cufflinks` called `set_config_file` and set the colorscale parameter, but it still doesn't get set as the default.

Comment: There isn't one I think, would you like a workaround solution?

Comment: Yes, please! Anything that will let me skip specifying the colorscale everytime execute a graph. 

On a side note, am I the only one that thinks that the plotly docs are not that descriptive or extensive?